# Custom built Java Mac app won't run when in /Applications folder

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java-based application that I've developed for a while now. When I create a Mac .app bundle, I do so by copying the following contents into the .app folder:

https://github.com/bobbylight/RText/tree/master/mac

When I build the .app, I notice the following:

- The application runs when I copy the .app onto my desktop, and double-click it.
- The application runs when I drag the .app directly to my task bar and click it.
- The application does not run when I copy the .app into my /Applications folder. I see a "do not enter" icon drawn over the app's actual icon, and trying to start it yields the error:
  "You can't open the application "RText" because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

The application does run from the /Applications folder if I run it from the command line:

```
cd /Applications
open -a RText.app
```

I do have the Java for OS X 2014-001 package installed for Java 6 support. I believe my Info.plist requires Java 6.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to debug this problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm on OS X 10.10.1. Here's the list of JVMs on my system:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
   1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
   1.7.0_09, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
   1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
   1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
$ env | grep -i java
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

Comment: open /Applications/Utilities/Console.app you will see various log files (including system.log) that may help to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of handy info I need on OS X - where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, a logout and log back in cleared things up.  I did a re-install of OS X 2014-001 before logging out/in, so I'm not sure if that was the magic or not.  I hate it when things magically clear up and I can't see why, but oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and logging out and back in as bobby_light suggests worked as well. As per ben75's comment I had also used `Console.app` to look for more information, so I'm posting this to shed some light on the situation:

An older version of my app had been previously installed in `/Applications` and was packaged to run using `JavaApplicationStub`. A new version of the app which used `JavaAppLauncher` was then dragged to `/Applications`.

`Console.app` revealed that double-clicking the app in `/Applications` was using the older information stored in `Info.plist` within the `.app`, and trying to run `JavaApplicationStub`. Somehow logging out seems to clear this cached info.